Can't connect Django server to Cassandra DB (AstraDB)
I've hosted my Cassandra DB on AstraDB and am trying to connect my Django server to it. This is the first time I'm working with Django too so I'm a bit confused on how it works. In my settings.py file, this is my code
from pathlib import Path
from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import dse

load_dotenv()

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECURE_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blogs',
    'graphene_django',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = ['django_cassandra_engine'] + INSTALLED_APPS

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django_cassandra_engine.sessions.backends.db'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
        'NAME': 'jasontechblog',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'connection': {
                'auth_provider': PlainTextAuthProvider('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET'),
                'cloud': {
                    'secure_connect_bundle': 'secure-connect-jasontechblog.zip'
                }
            },
        }
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

I've made sure that all of my secret keys and IDs are correct, though when I try to run python3 manage.py syncdb to sync my models to the db (like establishing tables, not sure if this is the correct termonology), I get this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 76, in register
    connection.get_connection(name=self.alias)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dse/cqlengine/connection.py", line 242, in get_connection
    raise CQLEngineException("Connection name '{0}' doesn't exist in the registry.".format(name))
dse.cqlengine.CQLEngineException: Connection name 'default' doesn't exist in the registry.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1286, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1332, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 979, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1458, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dse/datastax/cloud/__init__.py", line 128, in read_metadata_info
    response = urlopen(url, context=config.ssl_context, timeout=timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:1006)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jasontan/Documents/Jason/jason-tech-blog/jason-tech-blog/server/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/jasontan/Documents/Jason/jason-tech-blog/jason-tech-blog/server/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/apps.py", line 60, in import_models
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/apps.py", line 57, in connect
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/base/__init__.py", line 108, in connect
    self.connection = CassandraConnection(self.alias, **settings)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.register()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 86, in register
    cluster = Cluster(**self.cluster_options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dse/cluster.py", line 1031, in __init__
    cloud_config = dscloud.get_cloud_config(cloud)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dse/datastax/cloud/__init__.py", line 90, in get_cloud_config
    return read_metadata_info(config, cloud_config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dse/datastax/cloud/__init__.py", line 131, in read_metadata_info
    raise DriverException("Unable to connect to the metadata service at %s" % url)
dse.DriverException: Unable to connect to the metadata service at https://9b4178b8-3300-48f8-b03b-cdf66785c621-us-east1.db.astra.datastax.com:29080/metadata

I'm wondering if I've missed something? or if there's something incorrect in my settings.py file?
For context I'm using:
Django==5.0.4
django-cassandra-engine==1.9.0
cassandra-driver==3.29.1

I've tried searching online for solutions but I can't determine the issue in my code. I'm expecting in the DB that I can see a table describing a model I've defined

By the looks of the error, chances are Django is not directly involved. You may try if the Cassandra driver itself can connect:
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster  
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider   
  
cluster = Cluster(  
    cloud={"secure_connect_bundle": "secure-connect-jasontechblog.zip"},  
    auth_provider=PlainTextAuthProvider("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET"),  
)  
  
session = cluster.connect()  
print(session.cluster.metadata.cluster_name)  

Additionally, check the status of the DB on your Astra console (is it perhaps hibernated?)

Thanks for the question!  Based on the error message you're reporting it looks like your Python install doesn't have support for the set of ciphers supported by Astra's SSL implementation.  You'll need something that can work with one of these cipher suites:
PORT    STATE SERVICE
29042/tcp open  unknown
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|   ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|   compressors:
|       NULL
|   cipher preference: client
|   TLSv1.3:
|   ciphers:
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|   cipher preference: client

I would expect that any reasonably modern version of OpenSSL should handle these quite nicely.
